# Cursor with index on a large collection seems not to be detected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm running a `standalone mongodb 3.6` docker container and I have a collection which contains very small documents and I have a super simple index on the "Date" field set by descending:

```
> db.collection.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "myApp.collection"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "Date" : -1
                },
                "name" : "Date_-1",
                "ns" : "myApp.collection",
                "sparse" : true
        }
]
```

I'm using the MongoCSharpDriver to perform a query where I get the cursor and I'm getting the following error:

```
Command find failed: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: errmsg: "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit."
```

I'm specifying a `BatchSize of 100` documents however I'm not setting the limit of records to be returned since I think that will be handled by the cursor itsef (so both `Skip` and `Limit` are set to zero).

My question is, could it be that the actual index is already greater than 32MB? If so, is it that I have to extend the RAM allocated for this? Otherwise how do you solve this kind of issue? Note that I have 46132 documents right now each of them with a size of approx. 2.52 KB

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend the RAM. Set **allowDiskUse** instead of abort the operation it will continue using disk file storage instead of RAM, if the **allowDiskUse** has been set to true.

```
db.getCollection('movies').aggregate( [
  { $sort : { year : 1} }
],
{ allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

And also, I can't see your query, but you said you have some index, always before that ordering, you need to create index.

Comment: AllowDiskUse is only available from v4.4 isn't it? I thought of that already but I don't think I can use it can I? Regarding the query, let's say it's an empty filter so that it would iterate through all documents of the collection. I didn't get the last bit of the create index since I posted I already have one?

Comment: Actually I think I may be able to use it via the driver: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/interfaces/FindOptions.html it says from MongoDB 3.2 and above?

Comment: It does not work. The query fails saying failed to parse

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas Yes, its from 3.2 and + . Can you write me your query and full error msg?

Comment: Looks like with the mongo c# driver it does not support that? The full error message is the one specified in the description of the question

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas  Im sure you can do it
`var aggregateOptions = new AggregateOptions{ AllowDiskUse = true};
var aggregateResult = collection.Aggregate(aggregateOptions);`
Or for older version its `new AggregateArgs `